# Country-specific configuration

Tags: symfony

I'm preparing to work on an application that should support different countries, so I need support for:

- currencies
- numbers formatting (for prices etc.)

Switching locales will be based on http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle.

Now I need to store information about locale specific stuff like currency, currency divisor, precision etc + some other country specific data.

What is the best way of doing that in Symfony 2? I know there's a Money field type in SF2 forms, but I will need to display prices etc all over the app, so maybe there's a bundle or something that might help?

I don't want to store information like that in config "parameters", rather in a DB table maybe and use a number_format then, but maybe someone has better ideas?

I'd really appreciate any input here! :)

**Edit**

One more thing came to my mind, validation constraints may differ for each country, for example phone number might have different lenghts in DE and, for example, in UK. Is it possible to define constraints based on locale? Or do I have to create my own constraint and inside that check locale etc?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled over this bundle recently, might be what you're looking for:
https://github.com/craue/TwigExtensionsBundle